# How do I route to a web server on a home network

Tags: networking

I am struggling to understand how a network works, specifically a home network, if I wanted to configure an external facing website.

Say I have 4 windows computers. They are all connected to a router which in turn is connected to the internet. I understand that all the computers will have private ip addresses and that these will map to one public IP address from the router.

If I have iis installed and working on one machine, is it possible to route a request through to that website without having to muck around with port forwardining?

For examples, if my web address internal is 192.168.1.12/testpage.html. If my router IP address is 82.12.13.14, can (as long as my firewall allows) call my testpage by calling 82.12.13.14/testpage.html? How will the router know what to do with this request?

Comment: This question should probably be moved to SuperUser as it's a system administration issue and not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to just [port-forward](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/) web traffic from your firewall to your web server.

In a nutshell, you have to tell your firewall to send all incoming on `<external IP>:80` to `<internal webserver IP>:80` and map source IP to `<external IP>` for outgoing packets on the same connection.